# NoneType object is not callable / pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

начал писать бота для телеграм, выдает ошибку:

> def send_welcome(message): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
> callable

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("тут мой токен")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi, you use bot-assistent Maidy")
```

Comment: предоставленный код в вопросе полностью работоспособен

Comment: можете показать в ошибку?

Comment: у меня нет, пишет " def send_welcome(message):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо bot.reply_to(message, "Hi, you use bot-assistent Maidy")
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi, you use bot-assistent Maidy")